# Fixed Page Contents- "sticky" header/nav

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, modern-pages, sitepages

I am trying to create a 'fixed'/floating table of contents/navigation for a SharePoint page such that the sidebar contains links to various parts of the page and these links remain visible as the user scrolls down.

Is there a better way to institute a page "table of contents" or a way to affix the sidebar in place?

[image: side bar table of contents]

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint out of the box approach:

You can use "Text" web part with headings (heading 1, heading 2, etc.) or sections headings which gives you direct hyperlink to heading/section.

Then you can use these hyperlinks in another text web part or quick links web part to create a table of contents on a page. To create links at right side of page, use [Vertical section](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899).

However, this will not create a fixed/sticky navigation and navigation will be hidden when you scroll down to the bottom of longer page.

**Reference**: [What is an Anchor Link in SharePoint Online?](https://www.orchestry.com/insight/tech/microsoft-sharepoint-online/sharepoint-online-anchor-links-how-what-why/)

---

Using SharePoint Framework (SPFx) approach:

If you want fixed/sticky header even when you scroll down on longer page, there are few custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) solutions available to achieve your requirements.

Check below links for detailed information and code. You can use these solutions as it is or you can enhance them as per your requirements:

1. [Table of Contents Web Part](https://dmitryrogozhny.com/blog/table-of-contents-spfx-web-part)

   [image]
2. [Table Of Contents for SharePoint](https://gitlab.lsonline.fr/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/toc)

   [image]
3. [Page Navigator](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-page-navigator)

   [image]
4. [Page Sections Navigation](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-page-sections-navigation)

Comment: thank you so much- I already use a vertical section with links to the headers on my page but need the fixed part so it remains visible while scrolling...will see if I can implement the custom SPFx solutions. Though I may be back here if I get stuck again! Again, thank you very much!

Comment: You cannot make it sticky using OOTB features. Try the SPFx solutions given in my answer. Let us know if you need any further help.

Comment: Still stuck:/ Ganesh- any chance I can get your help getting up and running with sharepoint framework? (sent you an email)